# Are there downsides to using calls to system() instead of your programming language's functions?

Tags: c, bash, system-calls

I'm programming in C to create some API for an embedded device. This embedded device runs a variant of Linux. I'm not very familiar with C - I'm more familiar with shell scripting/bash.

With that in mind, when it comes to things like checking whether a directory exists, or getting disk usage, I find it easier to just make a call to `system` or `popen` and execute my command, then parse the output. It's faster for me as a developer.

Are there downsides to making these `system` and `popen` calls instead of finding out how to do each of these things in C and then making use of C's functions?

Comment: You should write a bash script then. Why do you want it in c? And it's not true that it's easier, handling the output is painful.

Comment: @iharob The communication library only exposes a C interface, so I have to use C for the API. It's for an IP camera, and one of the API requests is "how much space is there left on the SD card?", for that I could either call some shell commands, or implement C functions regarding disk usage... but I'm already familiar with the shell commands.

Comment: Do everything with c, don't call system utilities. It's hard to parse their output in c.

Comment: @iharob that sounds like a valid downside, C functions have well documented and useable output that doesn't need grepping or filtering... meaning I'd be dealing with things on a case-by-case basis? If there's a easy shell command, use that, else, use the C function?

Comment: No, don't use any shell command from c at all, that would make a very dangerous c program.

Comment: What is the library you want to use?

Comment: Dangerous I mean the program will virtually execute anything, you can't be sure what it is going to execute.

Comment: @iharob http://nabto.com/#download-list the uNabto library is what I'm using for communications. ... Additionally, I understand executing user input might not be the best, but why would hardcoded e.g. `system("[ -e /mnt/sd/video ]")` be able to execute anything?

Comment: @iharob It's not executing shell commands that's dangerous, it's executing  *arbitrary, untrusted user input* as a shell command that's dangerous. Constructing command lines in your code from values you control is perfectly safe (although inefficient).

Comment: @chepner Not necessarily, if you change the current user `PATH` environment variable and place  malicious script with the name of some of the programs executed by the c code, then ...!

Comment: @chepner - Only if you know **exactly** what you're doing, and you don't miss a single thing.  For example, the `IFS` environment variable.

Comment: You can hard-code the path names for the actual commands. If somebody has replaced `/bin/ls`, for example, with malicious code, well, you have bigger problems on the system than your program.

Comment: How about if the user set LD_PRELOAD to run their `system()` instead of the libc-supplied `system()`?  No system compromise needed.

Comment: For my security model, when a customer has root or physical access to their system, I don't care anymore. If someone can touch the camera, they can grab a hammer and smash it to a thousand tiny bits. Being able to solder a wire onto it and loading it full of malicious commands just to make my code do evil things is irrelevant, because by that point you could just have removed my code and put your own there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, on a Linux system, pretty much everything is calling C functions at some point.

To touch on some of the arguments in comments as well as my own thoughts:

1. Executing shell commands from a c program, especially when using user arguments, is a potential vulnerability.  Example would be if you allowed the user to call your program with the argument "foo; rm -rf *"; depending on how you invoke the shell, there's the potential you could effectively call "mkdir foo; rm -rf *" if you wanted to make the directory the user provided.  This may or may not be a big deal depending on how you trust your users etc.
2. Executing shell commands leads to potential race conditions that you can't avoid that might be more easily dealt with using straight system calls that you chain together
3. Parsing output of commands means dealing with more string operations in C, which is less than fun.
4. If you really prefer bash, your best bet is to probably implement small programs which wrap discrete portions of your target library's C API.  This is the UNIX way(tm) anyways.

EDIT to address Pimgd's comment: Note that race conditions are a pain in the neck and a lot of them aren't necessarily an issue for your particular use case, but are at least worth considering when weighing pro's/con's.  Anyways, the specific race-condition instances I was thinking about include (and there are likely other classes):

1. Security type race conditions.  If you create a temp file containing a set of commands and then execute it, there is the possibility that between creation and execution, someone goes in and modifies the file.  (There are actually a variety of variations on this theme for things like setting/resetting sym links etc.).  Based on your above comments, this is pretty much outside the scope of your project, but is something to be aware of for other applications.
2. Multi-process race conditions.  The simplest example I can think of is what happens if two instances of your program want to set a configuration file and are running at the same time.  There are certain OS calls which have certain levels of guarantee on atomicity, but you lose a lot of that if you call a series of shell commands to write to the file.  (note that even if you do it from a monolithic C application versus a series of shell commands, you still would need to do something extra to prevent instance 1 from overwriting instance 2's change, but you're at least not likely to run into the case that you end up having changes intermixed.  As an example consider:

   FILE *fp = fopen("config.txt","wt");

   fprintf(fp,"Config value 1: %s",config[0]);

   fprintf(fp,"Config value 2: %s",config[1]);

   fflush(fp);

   fclose(fp);

vs.

```
system("echo Config value 1: `df | awk '{print $1}'` > config.txt");
system("echo Config value 2: `ps | grep foo | awk '{print $2}'` >> config.txt");
```

Where, if two instances of the program run at close to the exact time, you can end up with e.g. 2 instances of Config value 2 in the config file in the latter case.

Comment: Nice list. It's easy to understand the points people are making like this. You  bring up potential race conditions? Is this inherent to using shell commands, or are you talking about things like using shell commands to do a task in the background, which will be done at some point in the future (representing a half-processed state in between?).

Answer (score 4):

Even if it is going to work on Linux, you can't rely on the availability of all the commands you intend to use, so the downside is straight forward: *you can't rely on a given tool being available*.

One more thing to consider is that parsing the output of shell commands from c is terribly difficult.

And finally, you can't make your program randomly call a system utility or shell script simply because it's unsafe.

Comment: Good point about availability, this could be a problem. It's not a problem for me in particular (writing the code for 1 specific system), but it could have been. Parsing of the output is sometimes easy, sometimes hard. Depends on what you're doing, really. As for the last point, as others have said, it's the user input or random input executed in system that's a risk - executing hardcoded commands carries far less risk.

Comment: @Pimgd less is not `0`, but makes me think ... there is never `0` risk. Try this `echo 'echo "This is a virus, I will delete your home directory."' > ls; chmod +x ls; export PATH=${PWD}:${PATH};` and now just list the directory content `ls`, now do you understand what I mean?.

Comment: I just forget that I did that and now it's printing `This is a virus, I will delete your home directory.` every time I type `ls`, which is very often. See, it's mean.

Comment: To make this change, you need to be able to access with enough rights to rewrite it. This requires you to bypass the current security of the camera. My security model doesn't include defending against threats which have this level of access, because instead of changing `ls`, they'd just change `myExecutable`. Or just flash a rootkit onto the internal memory.

Answer (score 4):

Cons:

1. it is insecure if there are user input
2. it is difficult to parse the output
3. it will relies on something external, such shell script.
4. heavy process - system fork() and start the other program in parallel

Pros:

1. easy to implement
2. depends of program output parse could be very easy. example `system("ls -1");`

Summarize -

It depends what you need to do, but in general case there more negatives than positives.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a valid approach for you being more familiar with shell scripts to do it like this:

Use a shell script as base which does all the high-level computations.  This script can use one (or more) commands to address the API; only to provide these commands, write small C programs.

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
valueA=$(APIhelper -q valueA)
valueB=$(APIhelper -q valueB)

process() { … }

result=$(process "$valueA" "$valueB")

APIhelper -s result "$result"
```

This part should be clear if you understand shell scripts.

Now you only need to write the binary `APIhelper` (please choose a more fitting name based on your context ;-).

That can be a C program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    if (strstr(argv[1], "-q") == 0) {
      if (argc > 2) {
        char *variableName = argv[2];
        someType result = makeYourApiCall(variableName);
        printf("%O\n", result);  # use a fitting format instead of %O!
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "-q without variable name\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    else if (strstr(argv[1], "-s") == 0) {
      …
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "option not understood: %s\n", argv[1]);
      exit(1);
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "missing option\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This way only the most basic handling of the API is done in the C program and you can stick to using what you can code best in: scripts.  Also, this way you can easily debug your API because this tool `APIhelper` can be called from the command line interactively.

Comment: This approach works best for simple values like integer numbers and small strings.  It will be complicated (and then probably not feasible) if your API handles complex data structures like dictionaries of lists of records of whatever.

Comment: This seems like a great way to handle things if the library exposed its interface in shell scripts. Sadly (but perhaps more logical on their end) it exposes its interface in C, so my code is more like a webserver serving a bunch of .cgi would look like, each doing a small and simple function after going through a massive switch. Kudos for the idea behind this approach though.